# Submanifolds and their tangent bundle

Tags: manifolds, complex-geometry

For X, we defined the holomorphic tangent bundle by the $\mathit{Jacobi}$ of the transition map $\varphi_{ij}=\varphi_i\circ\varphi_j^{-1}:\varphi_j(U_i\cap U_j)\cong\varphi_i(U_i\cap U_j)$ $$J(\varphi_{ij})(\varphi_j(z)):=(\frac{\partial\varphi_{ij}^k}{\partial z_l})_{k,l}.$$
Now Let$Y\subset X$ be a complex submanifold. $\mathbf{My \ Question}$ is : when z$\in$Y, what is $J(\varphi_{ij})(\varphi_j(z))$ look like?(Like this one?$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}*&**\\ 0&***\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$)
The question comes from Lemma 2.2.15 of [Complex Geometry by Huybrechts](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Eshanyuji/Complex/Complexgeometry.pdf). It looks like a silly question, but I’m stuck.

Comment: The point is that you have to consider transition maps between charts adapted to $Y$, not just any chart. Then $Y\cap U_i$ gets identified with $\varphi_i(U_i)\cap\mathbb{C}^m$ and the transition map $\varphi_{ij}$ maps $\varphi_j(U_i\cap U_j)\cap\mathbb{C}^m$ and $\varphi_i(U_i\cap U_j)\cap\mathbb{C}^m$ into one another, so $J(\varphi_{ij})$ maps $\mathbb{C}^m$ into $\mathbb{C}^m$ in each tangent space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But that didn’t solve my problem. I want to get a injection relation between the tangent bundle $\tau_Y$ and $\tau_X|_Y$, which is shown in the book mentioned above.